# Creación de Script para convertir archivos .CSV en XLSX

Tags: csv, script, powershell, ejecutar, xlsx

Estoy creando un script .sp1 para ejecutarlo desde PowerShell para que me lea todos los archivos .csv que existan dentro de una carpeta y cree archivos .xlsx en otra carpeta.

En el nuevo excel creado debe salir cada dato en una nueva columna.

*Ejemplo:*

```
**Columa1 | Columa2 | Columa3 |**

Dato 1  | Dato 2  | Dato 3  |

Dato 1  | Dato 2  | Dato 3  |

Dato 1  | Dato 2  | Dato 3  |
```

Código

```
#- Especificar el delimitador utilizado en el archivo CSV. Cambio de ',' a '\t' (tabulador).

$csvDelimiter = ","

#Ruta de los archivos CSV. (ADVERTENCIA: TODOS LOS ARCHIVOS CSV SERÁN CONVERTIDOS )

$csvLocation = "C:\Users\admin-\CSV"

foreach ($csvFile in Get-Childitem -Path $csvLocation -Filter "*.csv") {

    # Mostrar un mensaje indicando qué archivo se está convirtiendo

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Convirtiendo el archivo '$($csvFile.BaseName)' al formato XLSX."
    
    # Crear un nuevo objeto de aplicación Excel
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
    
    # Definir la ruta para el archivo XLSX de salida
    $xlsxFilepath = "C:\Users\admin-\XLSX\$($csvFile.BaseName).xlsx"
  
    # Crear un nuevo libro de trabajo en Excel
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
   
    # Seleccionar la primera hoja de cálculo en el libro de trabajo
    $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)
   
    # Definir la ruta del archivo CSV a importar
    $csvFilepath = ("TEXT;" + $csvFile.FullName)
    
    # Crear una tabla de consulta para importar los datos CSV en Excel
    $csvConnector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($csvFilepath, $worksheet.Range("A1"))
    $query = $worksheet.QueryTables.item($csvConnector.name)
    
    # Establecer el delimitador para los datos CSV
    $query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $csvDelimiter
    $query.TextFileParseType  = 1
    
    # Establecer tipos de datos para las columnas (1 = texto)
    $query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = @()
    for ($i = 1; $i -le $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count; $i++) {
        $query.TextFileColumnDataTypes += 1
    }
    
    # Ajustar el ancho de las columnas
    $query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1
    
    # Establecer la plataforma del archivo de texto (solución UTF8)
    $query.TextFilePlatform = 65001
    
    # Actualizar la tabla de consulta para importar los datos
    $query.Refresh() | Out-Null
    
    # Eliminar la tabla de consulta después de importar los datos
    $query.Delete()
    
    # Agregar una referencia a la librería Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
    Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
    
    # Ajustar automáticamente el ancho de las columnas
    $worksheet.Columns.AutoFit() | Out-Null
    
    # Agregar una tabla con estilo a la hoja de cálculo
    $table = $excel.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlListObjectSourceType]::xlSrcRange, $excel.ActiveCell.CurrentRegion, $null ,[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess]::xlYes)
    $table.Name = "TableData"
    $table.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium20"
    
    # Guardar el libro de trabajo como archivo XLSX
    $workbook.SaveAs($xlsxFilepath, 51)
    
    # Cerrar la aplicación Excel
    $excel.Quit()
    
    # - Comenta la sección siguiente si no deseas eliminar el archivo CSV después de la conversión.
    if (Test-Path "$csvLocation\$($csvFile.BaseName).xlsx") {
        Remove-Item -Path $($csvFile).FullName -Force
    }
}
```

- Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por qué convertirlos? Si prácticamente cualquier aplicación -incluyendo Excel- los abre sin problema.

Comment: Para practicar, ejercicio de clase.